# How to download local html file in streamlit application?

Tags: python, html, pandas, streamlit

I write a program that generates an HTML report. First, my program performs the calculations and saves them in the DataFrame. The next step is to add some text before DF, format DF and save the ready HTML report. This code looks like this:

```
html = f'''
     <html>
         <head>
            <title>Some title</title>
         </head>
         <style type ="text/css">
           Here I have some table formatting like:
           table {{
               font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
               width: 100%;
               text-align: center;
               border-collapse: collapse;
               }}
               
          </style>
          <body>
             Here I write some text before DF like:
             <h1 style="text-align: center;">Some Text</h1>
             Next, I use my DF:
             {DF.to_html()}
         </body>
      </html>
    '''
```

Next step is to save the ready HTML file:

```
        with open('report.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(html)
```

The last step is to download this HTML file by st.download

```
st.download_button(label="download report",
                               data='report.html',
                               file_name="test_report.html")
```

When I try to open the downloaded test_report.html file, inside is only "test_report.html". I tried to open the file named: "report.html" and this looks like it should, I mean this is my ready-formatted report. I probably made something wrong when I downloaded "test_report.html", but I don't know what.

Comment: I solve my problem, I open html file using open("report_html", "r") as f, and i download this f file as ready HTML report